# Xamarin Forms 4 UWP Error: build action embeddedresource is not supported by projects with an output type of appcontainerexe

Tags: xamarin.forms

I migrated projects from NETFramework to NETStandard and I copied files from old projects to new ones.

When I build new project, the UWP one, I got error:

> Build action embeddedresource is not supported by projects with an
>   output type of appcontainerexe for `Strings.resx` file.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Have you checked this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=windows)?

Comment: I checked and is not helpful. In NETFramework works fine, but not when I use NETStandard, I'm talking about migration from netframework to netstandard !

Comment: Yep, I know that, the above link is  Xamrin.Form official document about Localization, and it is based on the `netstandard`. I mean you could re-create the string resource  refer to this document.